# No '/' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'CGPoint' - Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I just change my CGContextAddArc to addArc and now I am getting this error:

```
No '/' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'CGPoint'
```

Here is the code:

```
context?.addArc(center: (frame.size.width)/2, radius: frame.size.height/2, startAngle: (frame.size.width - 10)/2, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: 1)
```

what adjustments to I need to make to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just passing in a `CGFloat`, `center` is expecting a `CGPoint`

e.g.

```
context?.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2) ...
```

Comment: No problem, I don't find Swift errors very helpful. Also check your start angle, is this what you need it to be? It should be the angle in radians where your arc begins.